# How to override the base url in an href tag in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component in angular that looks like this:

```
<div class = "notification__text__container">
   <span class = "notification__text">{{
       notification.notificationText}} </span>
</div>
```

I would like to make this div a link to another part of my web page like this:

```
<a 
href = "/user/notification"
class = "notification-notification-clickable"
>
<div class = "notification__text__container">
   <span class = "notification__text">{{
       notification.notificationText}} </span>
</div>
</a>
```

However, I am noticing that it is appending my href onto a base URL that is slightly incorrect: it is taking me to the page:

```
'www.mySite.com/inc/user/notifications'
```

when I want it to go to

```
'www.mySite.com/user/notifications'
```

without the 'inc'. Is there a way I can dynamically change the base url here, or specify it to remove the 'inc'?

Comment: The right approach would be using `routerLink` instead of `href`. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink check this out. Let me know if you face any issue adding router link in your html